# Creating QGIS project file without installing QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qml

#### Goal

We want to automatically create QGIS projects (preferably in python), including a given set of Layers.

#### Approaches

1. We thought of creating a project file by defining it in a .qml file given a plain .qml file created by QGIS. But while testing it, we saw that new content changes the .qml file in multiple places (e.g. adding a layer) and came to the concluion that it would be an unnecessary complex and error-prone way of doing this.
2. I already used the QGIS API to do this and it worked. But since this is our only use case for QGIS it would be quite an overload to install the whole QGIS application on our server environment just to create projects.

So far I could not find a way to use the necessary libraries without really installing the application, which would in my eyes be the optimal solution.

Is there another way that I'm not seeing yet?

#### Technical details

Used Python QGIS API of QGIS 3.22.5-Białowieża

Resulting QGIS project file version should be >=3

Comment: Is it a really lean server environment? QGIS is only like 1gb in size, it does not seem like such a huge overload imo.

Comment: Depends on the use case I would say, but yes we now do have it running in the server environment. You were talking about the pure disk space taken from the program right? Because the docker image we are using for convenience has ~8gb (including OS). Or is there a slimer verson I haven't found yet?